# Is there a "final" FINAL screenplay for Highlander?

Tags: highlander, highlander-franchise

If you look at Gregory Widen, Peter Bellwood & Larry Ferguson's *Highlander* [screenplay as of 2/6/1985](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/Highlander_final.txt), most of it is nearly 100% identical to the movie (the plot and even the lines).

Everywhere I saw, it was billed as "final".

However, it differs from both US release of the movie, and even the European-release-based Director's cut, in significant ways. Two examples are:

- Opening MSG sport was wrestling instead of hockey

  Wikipedia mentions that (according to DVD commentary) that was done for a reason.
- There was no closing scene where Rachel finds out that MacLeod survives from the fact that Kurgan was listed as the last victim by Moran; and flirts with Moran.

Is there a screenplay version (NOT the novelization) that's "more final" and matches the actual movie?

Comment: Things like those instances can change in production, and not make it into the shooting script. As is the case with some re-shoots or pick-up shots. Other than transcriptions, almost no shooting scripts corresponds 100% with the final film. Some "re-writes" even occur in the editing bay.

Comment: @MeatTrademark  *"Some "re-writes" even occur in the editing bay."*  Too true.  I've sometimes watched movies that had me thinking 'What the huh?' only to later see the 'Directors Cut' that made everything entirely clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The screenplay for *Highlander* received extensive re-writes between the [early drafts](https://scifiscripts.com/scripts/Highlander_early.txt) by Gregory Widen in June 1981 and the [initial shooting script](https://scifiscripts.com/scripts/Highlander_final.txt) completed in Feb 6th 1985 by Gregory Widen, Peter Bellwood & Larry Ferguson, this being the latest version available on the internet.

There does seem to exist a "[final shooting script](https://www.amazon.com/dp/product/B0045Q3HI2/)" that was revised up to June 21, 1985 (e.g. beyond the start of principal filming) but you'll need to pay cashy-money to get hold of it. This booklet was apparently available through the official *Highlander* mail order catalog.

[image: blue booklet of first draft screenplay]